# ALU design error

Tags: vhdl, bit, modelsim, alu

I want to design an 8 bit alu in VHDL but I get this errors, I think it has something to do with the fact that my inputs are declared as bit_vectors. Is that true?

```
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(19): No feasible entries for infix operator "+".
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(19): Type error resolving infix expression "+" as type std.STANDARD.BIT_VECTOR.
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(21): No feasible entries for infix operator "-".
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(21): Type error resolving infix expression "-" as type std.STANDARD.BIT_VECTOR.
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(23): No feasible entries for infix operator "-".
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(23): Type error resolving infix expression "-" as type std.STANDARD.BIT_VECTOR.
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(25): No feasible entries for infix operator "+".
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(25): Type error resolving infix expression "+" as type std.STANDARD.BIT_VECTOR.
** Error: C:/Programs/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/alu.vhdl(40): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

This is my module:

```
entity alu is
 port ( bus_a : in bit_vector(7 downto 0);
 bus_b : in bit_vector(7 downto 0);
 state : in bit_vector (2 downto 0);
 out_c : out bit_vector(7 downto 0));
end alu;


architecture behave of alu is

begin

process(bus_a, bus_b, state)

begin
case state is
 when "000" => 
 out_c<= bus_a + bus_b; --addition 
 when "001" => 
 out_c<= bus_a - bus_b; --subtraction 
 when "010" => 
 out_c<= bus_a - 1; --sub 1 
 when "011" => 
 out_c<= bus_a + 1; --add 1 
 when "100" => 
 out_c<= bus_a and bus_b; --AND gate 
 when "101" => 
 out_c<= bus_a or bus_b; --OR gate 
 when "110" => 
 out_c<= not bus_a ; --NOT gate 
 when "111" => 
 out_c<= bus_a xor bus_b; --XOR gate 
 when others =>
 NULL;
end case; 

end process; 

end architecture behave;
```

Do you have any ideas why and maybe you have any other suggestions for the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bit_vector` is just a collection of `bit`s, but without any intrinsic value, so you have to tell VHDL how to understand the `bit_vector` as a value before it makes sense to use an arithmetic operator like addition (`+`).

Take a look a the `numeric_bit` package, which has the types `signed` and `unsigned` as array of `bit`, whereby you can specify that a `bit_vector` is to be considered as an either signed or unsigned value when doing addition.

So the library use and convert can look like below for unsigned addition:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;
...
out_c <= bit_vector(unsigned(bus_a) + unsigned(bus_b));  --addition
```

But usually the `std_logic_vector` is used instead of the `bit_vector`, so you may consider looking at the `std_logic_1164` and `numeric_std` packages instead.